# I am getting repated domain name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting repettative domain name in my URL

```
http://foo.example.com/foo.example.com/dashboard
```

Htaccess code

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

My desired output is `http://foo.example.com/dashboard`, does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: It is my shared hosting and  my other projects are working fine

Comment: I found the solution, it was in in my react code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Issue was in my react code.